# jQuery.get is not pulling data from a valid URL

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

#### TLDR

`jQuery.get()` correctly pulls the header information for one `select` option `onchange` value but not the others even though they are valid URLs.

---

#### Goal

To use jQuery and GitLab API to validate the header information of the `select` value when changed by the user and before submitting the form.

---

#### Process

- User selects a value from the `select` with class `opt0`.
- `onchange` calls jQuery.
- jQuery validates that the URL exists (and will eventually go on to verify details of the array).
- jQuery returns the array of the existing URL to the Chrome developer console (for the time being).
- jQuery will eventually return invalid URL as a console message or `alert()`.

---

#### Actual Results

The console is reporting that the project is not found for valid URLs.

Selecting each of the values results in the following console information:

- xxxxxxx: `(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`
- yyyyyyy: `jquery.min.js:2 GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/yyyyyyy/repository/tree 404 (Not Found)`
- zzzzzzz: `jquery.min.js:2 GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/zzzzzzz/repository/tree 404 (Not Found)`

Bear in mind that all URLs are valid and contain the correct array data that I am looking for.

---

#### Expected Results

My expectation is that since one URL works correctly that all should work correctly as they are all valid URLs. The following is an example of a desired result:

- xxxxxxx: `(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`
- yyyyyyy: `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]`
- zzzzzzz: `(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

---

#### Errors

Error messages returned:

- `{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}`.
- `jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxxxx/repository/tree`
- `jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/yyyyyyy/repository/tree`

I am logged into gitlab so authentication shouldn't be the issue.

---

#### Attempted

- `$.load()` - same result.
- `$.ajax()` - same result.
- `$.get()` - shown with error. Figured I would go with this due to it's simplicity.
- `parseInt(this.value)` - same result.
- `var url = encodeURIComponent("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/" + 
  parseIntthis.value) + "/repository/tree");`  - doesn't load URL
- Chrome developer console > Network > clear browser cache
- Chrome developer console > Network > XHR > Initiator -> Path and chain look to be correct.

---

#### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".opt0").change(function(){
                    var url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/" + this.value + "/repository/tree";
                    $.get(url, function( data ) { 
                        console.log(data);
                    }, "json" );  
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $menu = array('xxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyy', 'zzzzzzz');
            echo "<select name=selex class='opt0'>";
                echo "<option value=''>---</option>";
                foreach ($menu as $option) {
                    echo "<option value=$option>$option</option>";
                }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: I think it's clear that the project name is wrong.

Comment: I've updated the call from `"select"` to `".opt0"`. I had it coded correctly but somehow it got in the question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: All I mean is that `this.value` doesn't contain a valid project name on gitlab.com.

Comment: When you go to the same URL (for each project) in your browser (same browser, to ensure same session) what happens?

Comment: I've detailed that the URL is correct when I inject `this.value` into the URL.

Comment: The output is as it should be when going directly to the url, correctly showing the array of information.

Comment: Is API access enabled on all three projects?  I don't know a lot about gitlab...fact that you can get to those URLs in browser makes me think that it is but this feels like a difference of project configs and not a problem with this code.

Comment: All are permitted. One URL works where the others don't.

Comment: It's the same project.

Comment: I thought this.value was the name of the project.  I'll leave my comments in case they help anyone else figure this out, but I have no more ideas.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be an authentication issue after all.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".opt0").change(function(){
            var url1 = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/"+this.value+"/repository/tree";
            var settings = {
              "async": true,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "url": url1,
              "method": "GET",
              "headers": {
                "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "<your token>"
              }
            }
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```